# Howto safely go from 230V to 12 Volts

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, 12v

I'm playing around with different kind of 12 LED light sourcing. Normally I have used one of these 12 V power adapters (with EU plug). But I have got this idea of changing a halogen lamp with a home build LED lamp - so I need something safe that allows me to connect the 220 AC wires to some sort of light weight 12 V DC "converter" (I notice that most of the 12 DC power supplies are quite big and heavy).

Does such a solution exist ?

Comment: Why don't you use an off-the-shelf LED replacement bulb for the halogen lamp? Do you need to make a home built LED lamp?

Comment: SMPS is the solution, you can try "Power Integration". http://www.powerint.com/

Comment: @Andyaka I want to lasercut my own lamp and be able to install different kind of LEDs

Comment: You want to buy a solution or to make one?

Comment: Want to buy this as a component in my cuircut - which for now is simple since it's only a power supply and a LED component. But who knows, I might add a MCU to make some PWM and other fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-40W-12V-Halogen-LED-Lamp-Electronic-Transformer-Power-Supply-Driver-Adapter-/251333442321?pt=US_Lighting_Parts_and_Accessories&hash=item3a84a3fb11

Which looks like a solution. The only problem is quality and safety...

**EDIT** @Anthony pointed out the very important thing that these are AC and not DC transformers so found this one

http://www.ebay.com/itm/40W-12V-LED-DRIVER-CONSTANT-CURRENT-POWER-SUPPLY-TRANSFORMER-FOR-MR16-MR11-LEDS-/161077334059?pt=AU_Lighting_Fans&hash=item2580f5102b

Comment: That looks like it outputs 12V AC however, not DC!

Comment: Thank you for noting that.. I notice that one of my previous build didn't care about polarity http://www.ebay.com/itm/171090432165?ssPageName=STRK:MEWNX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649 So perhaps it will work after all..?

Comment: This looks like an answer to a [shopping question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) rather than an electronics design question.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick getting the right components is in my POV a important part of the design - this is how I learn what types of components (and their names) exist to solve different electronic tasks. I'm not asking if I should buy a Phillips og Borsch shaver.